# Configure FastCGI for PHP on Low MEM VM

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi

I have a VM with only 256MB of RAM that is running nginx and PHP 5.3. Since I am resource constrained (cannot change the amount of RAM in the VM) I am looking into the various ways of setting up FastCGI for PHP. Perhaps my Google-fu is weak, but I cannot seem to find much about my options when setting up FastCGI or any best practices advice.

I am interested in being direct to information on:

1. What FastCGI servers options are there?
2. Are any of these clearly better or worse than the others?
3. Considering my setup (256MB RAM, nginx) are there any clear resources or technical blogs that I should be following for advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using php-fpm to manage the fastcgi processes.

There are a lot of options to control the number of childs etc.

http://dotdeb.org has nice packages for Ubuntu/Debian.

For the basic setup see http://interfacelab.com/nginx-php-fpm-apc-awesome/